# Crewing from Vancouver to Mexico

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, transit, sea-travel

Can a crew member ineligible to enter the US enter US waters and stay onboard during transit?

Comment: Combined with your other post, can you not simply fly from Vancouver to Mexico and avoid US territory all together?

Comment: No, as entering US territorial waters requires you to be admissible to the United States.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid If you have a reference for that it would be an answer.

Comment: thanks all. Over $100 extra not going through US, and if B. Khalid is correct I won't be sailing unless Halifax direct to Bermuda then south.

Comment: Reference is that when you disembark, you are either checked by ICE or are required to report to the port master (where you are checked for cutoms/duties and immigration) - this is especially true on ports frequented by international vessels. ICE officers often board vessels that are anchored off coast to check for weapons, etc. So trying to avoid this by anchoring off shore wouldn't help.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think it's the coast guard that boards vessels in territorial waters, not ICE.

Comment: The boats are coast guard, but the agents are ICE + Coast Guard. The Coast Guard doesn't enforce immigration laws.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it is you're crewing is probably governed by the [Pleasure Boat Reporting Requirements](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/pleasure-boats-private-flyers/pleasure-boat-overview), and if not language similar to this would be found in whatever governs it no doubt:

> operators of small pleasure vessels, arriving in the United States from a foreign port or place to include any vessel which has visited a hovering vessel or received merchandise outside the territorial sea, are required to report their arrival to CBP immediately ... an application to lawfully enter the United States must be made in person to a CBP officer at a U.S. port-of-entry when the port is open for inspection.

So, no. Entering territorial waters is entering the country far as CBP is concerned.

Comment: "Entering territorial waters is entering the country far as CBP is concerned." Source?

Comment: Read the link. There's no provision for avoiding the need to lawfully enter, the various waiver programmes are for only people prequalified.

Comment: It says "arriving in the United States". I don't see anything that defines it as including transiting US territorial waters.

Comment: Because that's the meaning of "territorial", that those waters are subject to the country's laws, please refer to the Law of the Sea which is what defines the concept. As you see in the quote, "required to report their arrival to CBP immediately" is the law of the US, there is no granted right of passage. If you need more detail, read UNCLOS the  United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea.